# What is the proper way to format a GET request to retrieve all media items of the Instagram user "self"?

Tags: api, parameters, count, instagram, media

Looking at https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/ I have gathered that calling `https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN` will return "the most recent media published by the owner of the access_token."

In sandbox mode I understand that I will receive a maximum of 20 media items from this call. I also realize that the response code has a pagination object that I can use to retrieve up to 20 more media items (see below)

```
"pagination":  {
    "next_max_tag_id": "1387272337517",
    "deprecation_warning": "next_max_id and min_id are deprecated for this endpoint; use min_tag_id and max_tag_id instead",
    "next_max_id": "1387272337517",
    "next_min_id": "1387272345517",
    "min_tag_id": "1387272345517",
    "next_url": "https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/cats/media/recent?access_token=xxx&max_tag_id=1387272337517"
}
```

These are the listed parameters of this Request.

```
PARAMETERS 
ACCESS_TOKEN    A valid access token. 
MAX_ID          Return media earlier than this max_id. 
MIN_ID          Return media later than this min_id. 
COUNT           Count of media to return.
```

My question is: Is there a way to structure my GET request in a way that returns all media items from a single call? I understand that this is not possible in sandbox mode, given a user with more than 20 media items. If possible please provide a detailed explanation of the `COUNT` parameter.

I imagine a possible GET request would look like `https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN?COUNT=X`

Thank you. <3

Answer (score 0):

When you go live mode you can use the `count=` param to get more than 20 in one API call, however I have noticed that `count=33` is the maximum you can get for this API call, even if you anything more than 33, it only returns 33.

You still have to use the `pagination` in JSON response to get the next set of media items, easiest way is to use the `pagination.next_url` to make API call and get next set of media items